# INSERT on each id from SELECT

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I just added users into my Wordpress installation from another CMS, and now I need for each user id in `wp_users` insert new value with its id into `wp_usermeta`. Is there any ideas for this in SQL?

Comment: What value do you need to insert?  Something like `INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) SELECT user_id, 'keyname', 'newvalue' FROM wp_users` which makes use of an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with string literal values...

Comment: @Kirix: Please, backticks are for _code_, not for proper nouns.

Comment: @Kirix I will put in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SELECT statement as a source of values for an INSERT, like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_usermeta (id)
SELECT u.id FROM wp_users u
```

The IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to insert the rows that it can, and if any rows we try to insert are "duplicate" rows (throw an exception), then just let those rows not be inserted, and ignore the errors that would otherwise be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta(id)
SELECT id FROM wp_users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Making use of single-quoted string literals, you can use the [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax to simultaneously select all user ids from `wp_users` and insert string values into `wp_usermeta`:

```
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
  SELECT
    wp_users.ID, 
   /* Single-quoted string literals for meta key and value... */
   /* Substitute the key and value you want to insert */
   'new_meta_keyname', 
   'new_meta_value' 
  FROM wp_users
```